# Can't Enter Main Function in HoverIntent

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, menubar, hoverintent

My project consists of a menubar, and I would like to have the submenus display below when the mouse hovers over each button (hoverIntent). I am using the Wet-Boew (Web Experience Toolkit) (https://github.com/wet-boew/wet-boew) to create these features.

My project workspace consists of a main project php folder, including an index file which calls a jquery.min.js and subsequently the hoverintent.js and menubar.js.

Below is the start of the hoverintent.js:

```
(function($) {
      // Alert Point A
$.fn.hoverIntent = function(f,g) {
                // Alert Point B
    // default configuration options
    var cfg = {
        sensitivity: 7,
        interval: 100,
        timeout: 0
    };
    // override configuration options with user supplied object
    cfg = $.extend(cfg, g ? { over: f, out: g } : f );

                etc...
     })
```

My problem is that although I can reach the first alter point A I have in my code (and can generate the alter box), the program won't run the $.fn.hoverIntent = function(f,g){...} (where I have the second Alert Point B). I have a similar problem with my menubar.js (where the main functions of the code won't load).

What is usually the most common source of this problem and the best way to fix it?

It should be noted that I do call a jQuery earlier on in a different php project folder (still inside the project workspace) that has to do with a separate login program for this software. The Index file jumps to the login program to get the user's credentials before returning to the index document to display the main content.

I made sure this was the same jQuery file I later referenced in the index file before the hoverintent.js and menubar.js. Is this what is causing the issue?

Sorry I don't have all the code at this time to share, I will try to get the rest out soon. Thanks in advance.

----------------UPDATE-------------------------------

My main index file includes the head with the following code. Note the "../" are required since the wet-boew project folder is seperate from the main program project folder (index) in the workspace:

```
<head>
<script src="../wet-boew-master/build/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script async="async" src="../wet-boew-master/build/js/dependencies/outside-min.js"></script>
<script async="async" src="../wet-boew-master/src/js/dependencies/hoverintent.js"></script>
<script async="async" src="../wet-boew-master/build/js/dependencies/equalheights-min.js"></script>
<script async="async" src="../wet-boew-master/build/js/dependencies/resize-min.js"></script>
<script async="async" src="../wet-boew-master/build/js/i18n/en-min.js"></script>

<script src="../wet-boew-master/src/js/workers/menubar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<title>Title of the Project</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="images/icon.ico">

<script src="../wet-boew-master/build/js/settings.js"></script>

<link href="../wet-boew-master/build/grids/css/util-min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="../wet-boew-master/build/js/css/pe-ap-min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="../wet-boew-master/build/.../css/theme-min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="../wet-boew-master/build/.../css/theme-ns-min.css" /></noscript></head>
```

Further down, inside the body of the index we have the menubar:

```
<body>
  <div id="wb-body">
    <div id="wb-head">
      <div id="wb-head-in">
        <header>
          <div id="wu-bnr" role="banner">
            <nav role="navigation">
              <div id="wu-psnb" >
                <div id="wu-psnb-in">
                  <div class="wet-boew-menubar mb-mega" data-load="menubar" role="application" style="min-height: 28px;">
                    <div>
                      <ul data-ajax-replace="../wet-boew-master/demos/includes/menu-eng.txt" class="mb-menu" role="menubar">
```

At which point my menubar options and their respective submenus are listed as such:

```
<li *class=""* role="presentation">
<section role="presentation">
    <h3 role="presentation">
        <a href="index.php?location=activitiesMenu:index" role="menuitem" class="knav-1-0-0 mb-has-sm" aria-haspopup="true">
            <span class="expandicon">
                <span class="sublink"><?=$glb_string["activities"]?></span>
            </span>
            <span class="wb-invisible">(open the submenu with the enter key and close with the escape key)</span>
        </a>
    </h3>
    <div *class="mb-sm"* role="menu" *aria-expanded="false"* *aria-hidden="true"* **id="myHoverIntent"**>
        <div class="span-2" role="presentation">
            <ul role="presentation">
                <li role="presentation"><a href="index.php?location=activitiesMenu:index" role="menuitem" class=" knav-1-0-1" tabindex="-1"><?=$glb_string["views"]?><?=($language_set_variable == 'fr'?:)?></a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="index.php?location=activitiesMenu:create" role="menuitem" class=" knav-1-0-2" tabindex="-1"><?=$glb_string["create"]?><?=($language_set_variable == 'fr'?':')?></a></li>
            </ul>           
        </div>
    </div>
</section></li>
```

Would this be the correct location for my id="MyHoverIntent" (Bold **) in the code above?

It should also be noted that the italic code (*) above isn't changing (I'm assuming because the menubar and hoverIntent main functions aren't running). This would normally auto-update as the user hovers over each menubar option or leaves it. I know this because of the sample file that was included in the WET-BOEW folder that shows a fully functioning page (with a menubar and hoverIntent working) and these changes were observed in Firebug. Although for some reason Firebug showed that the sample never referenced menubar.js.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell what exactly you are doing that stops your code from working since we only have half of the code right now but a few things come to mind. First, the `hoverIntent` function will get called when you actually call it on a jQuery Object like so

```
$('#myHoverIntent').hoverIntent();
```

Second, make sure you are not doing that before the `hoverIntent` function actually gets defined and lastly, make sure you are passing `window.jQuery` into your [immediately-invoked function expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

Here is a fiddle of a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/G3vCS/

Comment: Tom, I have made updates to show more of my code in the index above. I tried including the: $(function(){ $('#myHoverIntent').hovertIntent(); }) In the hoverIntent.js, below the rest of the code (below the (window.jQuery);) however I am getting an error in my Firebug: "TypeError: $(...).hoverIntent is not a function." Also is my reference to id="myHoverIntent" in the correct div location? It is where the submenus begin for a specific dropdown on the menubar.

Comment: I have figured out how to get into the hoverintent.js file, however I now face two issues: I'm not sure what two parameters I should enter for the hoverIntent(). Generally it's $("myHoverIntent").hoverIntent( showNav , hideNav ); but those are undeclared in my code. What would I set them to? Also, inside the hoverintent.js function I can't enter any of the private functions that I am assuming are essential to the code: var track = function(ev) { alert("I am here3"); cX = ev.pageX; cY = ev.pageY; };
var compare = function(ev,ob) { ... }
var delay = function(ev,ob) { ... } etc...